# Removing specific parts of string without knowing exactly what to remove

Tags: android, string, replace, substring, trim

In my Maps application, Im allowing users to add a custom marker. This saves the lat, long, and their chosen title to Shared Prefs.
Example String

```
23.5678,18.0987,My Custom Marker_10.45567,56.37439,My Second Custom Marker_-10.45567,-56.37439,My Third Custom Marker
```

After long clicking a marker, it becomes draggable. The user drags it to a new position and lets it go. Upon letting go, they have three options...move here, cancel, and delete marker

I can move and cancel just fine. When wanting to delete the marker, I would need the Lat,Lon,Title to use .replace(). But, when a marker is long pressed to initiate a drag, new coordinates are tied to it, the only things that remains the same is the title. Also, the coordinate length may vary anyways, so that kind of limits my options.
So, I need to take the above string, and remove a set of lat,lon,title items using only the title.

Example: User long presses marker 2 (10.45567,56.37493,My Second Custom Marker), then decides they want to delete it. I need to remove that part of the string, and keep the rest. Also note, that the underscore separates each marker info, the commas separating coords and title name. So if the first marker was to be deleted, the underscore to the second marker would need to be removed as well.

Comment: do you mean that if i want to delete `(10.45567,56.37493,My Second Custom Marker)` then i must be left with `23.5678,18.0987,My Custom Marker_-10.45567,-56.37439,My Third Custom Marker`?

Comment: Yes sir, that exactly, but remember that we can only identify the whole portion using the Title EG: My Second Custom Marker. Also, if its the first marker, there will be no underscore at the beginning to delete, but it will be present with all others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will do it.

The result for your query was:

```
res = 23.5678,18.0987,My Custom Marker_-10.45567,-56.37439,My Third Custom Marker
```

Please not that this code is not efficient at all. There are many allocations and unoptimized searches.

```
static private String remove(String title, String data) {
    String result = "";
    String[] markers = data.split("\\_");
    for( String marker : markers) {
        String[] parts = marker.split(",", 3); // 3: limit the number of splits, in case you have commas in the title
        if(parts[2].equals(title)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(result.length() > 0) {
            result+='_';
        }
        result += marker;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, I was half way there too! Marking this as the answer, thank you my friend. Happy Coding :)